# Why do some post, listed under the "Mine" Tab, and the same posts listed tunder "Published" Tab

Tags: posts

I need some help to understand why some post are listed under "Mine" Tab and the same post listed under the "Published" Tab on the Post Page.  How do I remove the other tab from the table?

Answer (score 0):

That's a normal behaviour of the post list table.

It lists your posts to find it easily and at the same time other users published posts are listed in the published tab.

If you have a lot of posts you'll love this to get your post faster than in the published tab

To remove the 'mine' tab, even I never did it, I think you can hide it with a piece of css. Or you'll need to hook in the post list table class to remove this tab.